# How to get all files in a StorageFolder in Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, storagefolder

I want to get all files in a folder and its sub folders. but a flat query like this:

```
var allFiles = await myFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

throws a `ArgumentException` exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>
> Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

before I query subfolders one by one, isn't there any other way?

Comment: as far as I remember it's an OS internal first chance exception of no relevance... You can ignore it

Comment: @thumbmunkeys It doesn't give me `allFiles`, ignoring it won't solve the issue

Answer (score 5):

You want all the files and folder which are a descendent of the root folder, not just the shallow enummeration. For most folders the only way to enumerate all the contents and its subfolders content is:

1. Use `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()` for the files
2. Use `StorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync()` to retrieve the all the subfolders
3. Repeat recursively for all the subfolders you find in step 2.

There is a workaround for this if you are looking for a particular type of media. The instructions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx). These few combinations of locations and CommonFile/FolderQuery options will give a device deep search for media and return the ordered results.

Answer (score 1):

Use     `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName` This is a deep query too so the result will contain all of files from all of subfolders
AND IT WORKS! ;)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says that you get `System.ArgumentException` if:

> You specified a value other than `DefaultQuery` from the `CommonFileQuery` enumeration for a folder that's not a library folder.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR211591.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is strange! Looks like a bug in GetFilesAsync method with all CommaonFileQuery options except `DefaultQuery`. It is working fine with DefaultQuery.

```
  var allFiles = await myFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but `DefaultQuery` only gives top level files without subfolder files.

Comment: GetFilesAsync() and GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery) are the only supported forms outside of the media library.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, solved it by preloading file paths recursively:

```
private static List<string> mContentFilenames = new List<string>();


private static void preloadContentFilenamesRecursive(StorageFolder sf)
{
    var files = sf.GetFilesAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            mContentFilenames.Add(f.Path.Replace('\\','/'));
        }
    }
    var folders = sf.GetFoldersAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (folders != null)
    {
        foreach (var f in folders)
        {
            preloadContentFilenamesRecursive(f);
        }
    }

}

private static void preloadContentFilenames()
{
    if (mContentFilenames.Count > 0)
        return;
    var installed_loc = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var content_folder = installed_loc.GetFolderAsync("Content").AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (content_folder != null)
        preloadContentFilenamesRecursive(content_folder);
}

private static bool searchContentFilename(string name)
{
    var v = from val in mContentFilenames where val.EndsWith(name.Replace('\\', '/')) select val;
    return v.Any();
}
```

No idea why downvoted, there is no other way to get full filelist in WP8.1. MSFT for some strange reason corrupts its apis from version to version. Some of calls now returns "not implemented".